# Referencing external JS snippet hosted on BitBucket

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, bitbucket, src

When referencing an external JS snippet hosted on BitBucket it is not loaded and does not work.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/[PATH TO FILE]/files/test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
alert("Hello World");
```

When that same JS file is stored locally it works but when hosted on BitBucket, it does not. Any ideas why?

Could it be the length of the link that is the problem? - Its 109 characters long.

Comment: can you post the complete url?

Comment: *"Could it be the length of the link be the problem? - Its 109 characters long."* No, they can be much longer than that.

Comment: If the file isn't publicly-accessible, my guess is that you're getting an access denied error. Look in the web console.

Comment: @sudoman: No, the content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: So? It's still much more reasonable to put the content **in** your question, rather than elsewhere, making people follow links off-site.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did not want my user name to be publicly available, thats why I used pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your web console, you should see an error similar to this:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/path/here/files/test.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

You won't be able to execute it directly like that reliably cross-browser.